# Cannot get bugs to show in backlog board in VSTS

Tags: azure-devops

I'm in the UAT phase of a project I am trying to configure my board using custom columns so I can easily track the progress of bugs through their life cycle. It seems like this is possible, but yet it doesn't quite work.

The new, active & resolved columns all show bugs - however the other columns do not, even though I have mapped them to valid statuses. I can run a query and can see there are plenty of bugs currently set to "In QA".

Why aren't they appearing in the list?

Am I going about this wrong? Is there another way to get this kind of view?

[image: board]

Comment: What're states of Bug work item type? How do you map columns to these states?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s mainly caused the Kanban board **filter cards** condition hide some work items which not meet the conditions. So in Kanban board -> click filter cards -> make sure all filter cards are not selected.

Such as If all filter cards not selected, the Kanban board will shows all user stories and bugs. If Iteration select all, there won’t show all work items.
[image]

[image]

Also please check the query conditions are correct or not as the [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/mail2bug/issues/61) said.

---

Create and customize in inherited processes:

In Process Tab https://account.visualstudio.com/_admin/_process, create inherited process from Agile template.

[image]

Click Bug for the inherited process, in the **States Tab**, add new states in Resolved category so that the bug process is: New -> Active -> Resolved -> In QA -> QA Approve -> In UAT -> Closed.

[image]

In kanban borad -> settings -> columns -> set IN QA column bug state as In QA, QA Approve column bug state as QA Approve, In UAT column bug state as In UAT -> save.

[image]

Comment: I have removed all filters and nothing shows up in my columns that are linked to custom statuses - even though I know there are bugs that are set to these statuses..

Comment: How did you map the bug state with column In QA, did you use Agile process or a inherited process?

Comment: We have our own inherited process

Comment: My kanban board can work normallywith inherited process. Please also check the query conditions are correct as the issue said https://github.com/Microsoft/mail2bug/issues/61.

Comment: I also give my details steps to create and customize inherited process, and map columns in my answer.

Comment: Thanks - It is working now - turns out I had the Area path set to something other than the root - pretty strange that it needs to be the root to appear in the board.